# Accessing a relationship through another relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models: Trip, Visit, Park

The relationships are currently set up like:

```
class Trip < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :visits
end

class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :park, counter_cache: true
    belongs_to :trip, optional: true
end

class Park < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :visits
end
```

Basically, If I have a trip, what I want to return is a list of Parks visited on that trip.

I could iterate the visits and grab the parks and deduplicate but there's most likely a more "railsy" way to achieve this that I just don't know about.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "has_many through" relationship.

```
class Trip < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :visits
    has_many :parks, through: :visits
end

class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :park, counter_cache: true
    belongs_to :trip, optional: true
end

class Park < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :visits
end
```

You only have to add has_many :parks, through: :visits in Trip model. Then from Trip you can access to all parks using the parks relation.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Ah fantastic!  That's what I was missing!   I'm assuming that the dedupe the results, I can use `.distinct'.   I have a field on my Visit model called `trip_order`.  Is there a way to order by that field?  I currently have `        <% @trip.parks.order('trip_order asc').distinct.each do |p| %>
            <%= p.name %>
        <% end %>`.   but that gives me an "INVALIDCOLUMNREFERNCE". ?

Comment: @rctneil What is trip_order in your query ? Because the way you have written it looks like it is a column from the Park model. Also, something not related to your invalid column reference issue: are you sure Visit should be a child of Park ? Because then Visit will hold a foreign key "park_id" and what if a visit goes to multiple parks ? Maybe also looks towards "has and belong to many" relationships.. it is a slightly different concept but may fit your data structure better (for you to assess)

Comment: What type of field is trip_order? What kind of order do you want? you are calling that order on the parks collection.

Comment: Hi Bashir.  I'll take a look at my structure and get answers to all that posted here tommorrow. I'd literally just put my machine to sleep as you replied.  Thanks for the help tonight though!

Comment: @BashirHud `trip_order` is an integer field. A Visit is one single visit to a park. A visit cannot consist of multiple parks.  Two Parks visited would class as two visits. A visit basically consists of the date of visit and who went etc.  Basically I just wish to order, the parks of a trip by the `trip_order` which shows what order a park was visited on that particular trip.

Comment: @rctneil so what you need is Park: { has_many :visits }, Visit: { belongs_to :park } and finally a Trip { has_many :visits; has_many parks, through: visits }. If a Visit belongs to a Park, you can order the parks by the visit date. ie: Trip.first.parks.joins(:visits).order("visits.date")

Comment: @BashirHud Thanks for that.  That's exactly the set of relations I currently have.  Yeh, I guess I don't need trip_order and can just order by the date of visit.  I currently have this:  @trip.parks.joins(:visits).order("visits.date"). I have tried adding `.distinct` onto the end as I need each park only showing once but I get `PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`?

Comment: Try .uniq &:name
Where name its supose to be the attribute of the park do you want to distinct.

Comment: @BashirHud .uniq worked perfectly.  Not too sure where I would use &:name?

Comment: @BashirHud.  Actually, Using that i've just noticed I do actually need to sort this by "trip_order".  There are a couple of instances where A Trip contains two visits on a day so the visit date is the same but I need them in a specific order.  That is the trip_order that's stored as part of the Visit.

Comment: @BashirHud This does what I was after: `@trip.parks.joins(:visits).order("visits.trip_order").uniq`.  Thanks so much!